# C++ : typeid ignored low level const reference but not pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    const int i = 42;    
    auto *p = &i; // p is const int *. const is low level const
    auto &q = i; // q is const int &. reference to const is always low level
    cout << "p = " << typeid(p).name() << endl;
    cout << "q = " << typeid(q).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
p = pki
q = i
```

Why is `typeid(q)` not showing the character `k` indicating that it's a `const` reference? `q` is reference to a `const` and that is always low level.

Answer (score 5):

The `const` in case of reference is not really low-level (as opposed to the pointer case).

`typeid` is applied to the type of expression `q`. This expression immediately loses its reference type, per the following general rule

> **5 Expressions**
>
> **5** If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

Expressions in C++ never have visible "reference" types, which also means that `typeid` cannot "see" references. It cases like this it always sees lvalues or xvalues of non-reference types. In your case `typeid` sees lvalue expression of type `const int` as its agument.

The rest follows from the definition of `typeid` behavior

> **5.2.8 Type identification**
>
> **5** If the type of the expression or type-id is a cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid expression refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified type.

I.e. `typeid` simply ignores top-level const-qualification.

In pointer case the const-qualification you are referring to is a not a top-level one. It is not lost under `typeid`.

Note also that the definition of `typeid` contains the following rule

> **4** When typeid is applied to a type-id, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the type of the type-id. If the type of the type-id is a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid
>   expression refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified referenced type.

Its purpose is to make the behavior of `typeid` applied to typenames consistent with the above behavior of `typeid` applied to expressions. I.e. `typed` applied to typename ignores references and also ignores cv-quailifications that become top-level after reference removal.

For some extra examples

```
typeid(const int) == typeid(int);     // <- true
typeid(const int &) == typeid(int);   // <- true
typeid(int *) == typeid(int *const);  // <- true
typeid(int *) == typeid(const int *); // <- false
```

Comment: Thanks. I need some time to digest your response. Appreciate very much